# reportlab borderRadius is not working

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using reportlab 3.2 with python 2.7.
I'm trying to make put some text in a rounded panel like so:
[image]

but I'm getting:
[image]
I've tried using **borderRadius** but it is not making the corners round:

```
ps_title2 = ParagraphStyle(styles['Normal'],\
    fontName=helper.REG_FONT, fontSize=18, textColor=DARK_BLUE,\
    leading=22, backColor=LIGHT_BLUE, borderRadius=15)

pr2 = Paragraph('Interpretation summary<br/>something<br/>another thing', ps_title2)
pr2 = Paragraph('my paragraph<br/>something<br/>another thing', ps_title2)
elements.append(pr2)
```

I know another approach is using a table and know how to make a table an put the info in a table but do not know how to make the table corners round.
Drawing canvas is not a good idea because I don't know the coordinates of the section because depending on the content length it would change.
Any ideas how to make the corners round?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through the code and figured out that when border color is not set, border radius will not work; also you need to set borderWidth and borderPadding.
Here is what works:

```
ps_title2 = ParagraphStyle(styles['Normal'],\
    fontName=helper.REG_FONT, fontSize=18, textColor=DARK_BLUE,\
    leading=22, backColor=LIGHT_BLUE, borderRadius=15, borderColor=LIGHT_BLUE,  borderWidth=1, borderPadding=5)
```

Answer (score 1):

For `borderRadius` to work, you need to set the following values as well:

- `borderWidth`
- `borderPadding`
- `borderColor`
- `borderRadius`